# Compare case results to another data point

Tags: sql, oracle

i wanted to compare the result of a end as case with another datapoint that is within the query. I am using PL/sql

```
CASE WHEN zz.code <> '0' THEN 'NYC'
     WHEN zz.last IS NOT NULL THEN 'PARIS'
     ELSE 'LA'
END AS NEW_CITY,
```

----this is what i tried underneath that, and of course it doesn't work

```
CASE When me.current_City = 'NEW_CITY' then 'Same'
     Else 'Different'
end as Comparison
```

i want the comparison column to display

`'Same'` or `'Different'`

Comment: did you forget the question?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Did you mean to have `'NEW_CITY'` in quotes - I assume you meant to refer to the first case expression's column alias, not a literal value? And there isn't any PL/SQL in what you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to a column alias in the same level of query, except in the `order by` clause ([see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55280)).

You can either use an inline view and refer to the inner-query alias in the outer query:

```
SELECT ..., CASE When current_City = NEW_CITY then 'Same'
  Else 'Different' end as Comparison
FROM (
  SELECT ..., me.current_City, CASE WHEN zz.code <> '0' THEN 'NYC'
     WHEN zz.last IS NOT NULL THEN 'PARIS'
     ELSE 'LA' END AS NEW_CITY,
     ...
)
```

Or repeat the case expression:

```
CASE When me.current_City =
    CASE WHEN zz.code <> '0' THEN 'NYC'
      WHEN zz.last IS NOT NULL THEN 'PARIS'
      ELSE 'LA' END
  then 'Same'
  Else 'Different'
  end as Comparison
```

Depending on how many times you refer to it and how long the case expression is, the inline view approach is possibly cleaner, and easier to maintain (since you don't have to remember to modify multiple copies of the same expression). But if you *only* want to display `'same'` or `'different'`, then you don't need the separate `new_city` alias at all, and the second approach is probably OK. (But format it better to make it easier for someone coming along later to understand).